# What does printing an empty line do?

Tags: python

I know this question may well be the silliest question you've heard today, but to me it is a big question at this stage of my programming learning.

Why is the second empty line needed in this Python code? What does that line do?

```
print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
print ''
print 'Hello, world!'
```

Comment: I like the idea of herding questions, rounding them up and driving them across the plains of SO...

Comment: Donal, what do You mean by "herding questions" and "rounding them up"? Also, what is "SO"?

Comment: Sorry Donal, I spoilt your joke

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It prints an empty line, just as you have said.  It will leave a blank line in the output.  The print statement prints its arguments, and then a newline, so this prints just a newline.

You could accomplish the same thing with just:

```
print
```

Comment: Note that in Python 3+ you'd want to use `print()` as `print` does nothing

Answer (score 4):

A blank line is required between the headers and the body in an HTTP response, so a CGI script will print a blank line at just that spot. There's no need for the quotes though, since an unadorned `print` will output a blank line.

Answer (score 2):

Did you even tried to telnet web-server?
It needs \n.
So, it's what it does, you can write it in one line if needed.

```
print 'Content-Type: text/plain\n\nHello World'
```

Comment: it needs a blank line, you would need another `\n`

Comment: ~h-launchpad-net-c, what do You mean by "to telnet web-server"?

Comment: If you telnet port 80 any web server, you will notice that delimiter between commands is "\n"

Comment: @ ~h-launchpad-net-c:
What does this verb "to telnet" mean? How do You telnet port 80? I am sorry I am not a native English speaker and I am just a newbie in programming.

Comment: try to write in terminal
$telnet google 80
They write GET /
more info: http://forums.macosxhints.com/archive/index.php/t-10195.html

Comment: @ confiq:
Hello, confiq!!! Which terminal do you mean? Is it that black window (its title is "C:\Python25\python.exe" without quotes) that opens up after I type "google_appengine/dev_appserver.py helloworld/" into command prompt? If yes, then I simply can't type anything in there. The cursor is still flashing under the last line (which is "myfirstapplicationsuniquename on port 8080: http://localhost:8080" without quotes), but when I try to type, nothing changes in that black window.

Comment: @ confiq: Also, the link that You gave me seems to be for Linuix, but my computer is Windows, is it okay?

Comment: Well, telnet is program that works in CLI (terminal). Try "Start" then RUN and then type "cmd"
I don't use windows for ages...

Comment: @ confiq: Hello, confiq!!! When I type "$telnet google 80 GET" or "$telnet google 80" or "$telnet google 80 GET/" and press "Enter", I get a line saying that '$telnet' "is neither an external nor internal command, thus, it can't followed upon" (this is my translation of that line from Chinese - I am right now in Taiwan, computer has Chinese platform, so those lines come in Chinese characters). Do you have any idea what that would mean?

Comment: For the newest windows versions you have to install it from the windows software control panel. Its called "Telnet Client".

Comment: RF2616 seems to suggest that CRLF is required http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

Comment: so interesting the question and the answers are~~ great~