# Function does not print expected result

Tags: python, function

```
def white():
    print
print ("First line")
white()
print ("Second line")
```

This is one of my first scripts.  When I press the "F5" key, this is the result:

```
First line
Second line
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Your `white` method doesn't actually do anything...

Comment: if `def` didn't work, you'd be getting a NameError because you failed to define anything. :P

Comment: It's really okay that you are learning, but try using google first (there a re really good tutorials out there: http://www.learnpython.org/)

Comment: @Alvaro What search term would you supply to Google?

Comment: @David Heffernan "python 3 print blank line"

Comment: @Alvaro This is a tricky question. I don't think "try using google first" is appropriate advice here. If you google "python print" and get documentation for Python 2.x it would be very confusing why there's no newline. You'd only google "python 3" if you'd already identified the source of the error!

Comment: @Alvaro That relies on the asker knowing ahead of time that `print` is very different in  Python 3 and Python 2. See where a search for "python print blank line" takes you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575584/what-does-printing-an-empty-line-do

Comment: @DavidHeffernan possible, but I knew that difference even before learning what def does

Comment: @Alvaro That's nice for you, but I can assure you that Python 2/3 issues are not at the forefront of the typical novice programmer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you are posibly right, I just read it from python.org before choosing wich version to download (any tutorial explains this). You have a valid point anyways --->

Comment: Hi @user3207246, in the future please make sure to include not only your actual output, but also your expected output (or a description of what is wrong with the output you are getting). I couldn't tell what the question was asking until I read the answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You are using Python 3 in which `print` is a function. In Python 2 `print` is a statement and your code would behave as you expect.

This line:

```
print
```

does not call the function. It merely looks up the name `print`. And that does not result in anything being place on the output device.

You presumably meant to write something like this that actually calls the function:

```
def white():
    print()

print ("First line")
white()
print ("Second line")
```

**Output**

```
First line

Second line
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2 `white()` prints a new line, whereas in Python 3 it does not.

```
$ python2 /tmp/white.py
First line

Second line
$ python3 /tmp/white.py
First line
Second line
```

The behavior of `print` changed between Python 2 and Python 3. In Python 2 `print` is a keyword, and writing simply `print` prints a new line.

In Python 3 `print` is a function and requires parentheses. If you write just `print` then you've got a statement which simply retrieves the `print` function but does not call it, so nothing happens. To get a blank line, you need to *call* it:

```
def white():
    print()
print ("First line")
white()
print ("Second line")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python 3, then 'print' is a function, and not a statement.  In order to print a line you need to actually call it.

```
def white():
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `white()` method to print whitespace, you need the print statement on line two to look more like this: `print(" ")`. A call to `print` without arguments won't do anything.

Comment: The point is that `print` in Python 3 is not a **statement** rather it is a **function**.